# Unable to profile OpenCL code using NVidia Visual Profiler

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL code which adds two arrays and prints the output. I want to profile this program using NVidia Visual Profiler that comes with CUDA Toolkit 3.0. I selected the appropriate program(.exe) to profile and the program directory. The profiler runs the code successfully but is unable to generate profiling results. It gives the error "Empty Header found in CSV file". What could be the problem for this? Is it necessary to build the code using NVidia's CUDA compiler to be able to profile? Please help me in this regard.

Thanks,
Rakesh K.

Comment: You could try a more low level approach for profiling using http://fakenmc.github.io/cf4ocl/. I developed it for my projects, so I don't depend on proprietary profilers such as NVidia Visual Profiler or AMD CodeXL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your driver and your OpenCL Visual Profiler versions are in sync. i.e. have you installed the correct 3.0 driver?

Also, to ask the obvious, are you using the OpenCL Visual Profiler and not the CUDA Visual Profiler? In 3.0 they are two separate tools. In 3.1 (currently in beta) they are merged into a single tool.

Answer (score 0):

Offer a problem example of mine, might be help:

problem:

Nvidia Visual Profiler just prompts No Timeline in Analysis Results of my OpenCL code, but profiling Nvidia offered OpenCL example, like MatrixMul, VectorAdd, is ok. (In command line, my code runs ok)

solution:

I try to run my program in windows cmd instead of mingw shell, and it prompts can't find "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll". (I use codeblock+mingw in windows 7). After libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is copied from mingw to my code working directory, Nvidia Visual Profiler can profile my code successfully now. The problem is caused by that Visual Profiler calling windows cmd instead of mingw shell. 
Hope this can help some others. 
Good luck!

Comment: Do you think this is the same issue?

Comment: I don't think so. But anyway he can try my method to see what will happen.